# iam trying to make todo list using JavaScript with local storage but while reloading the task is not saving in local storage,

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to make a todolist web app JavaScript, HTML, with local Storage feature in it. When I entered task in input element and click on add button the task should save to local storage but while reloading the page the tasks getting cleared.

```js
let inputText = document.getElementById("inputId");
let button = document.getElementById("addBtn");
let container = document.getElementById("list");


button.onclick = function(){

    let stringifiedTodoList = localStorage.getItem("todoList");
    let parsedTodoList = JSON.parse(stringifiedTodoList);

    localStorage.setItem("todoList",JSON.stringify(inputText.value));
   
    let inputFeild = document.createElement("p");

    if (inputText.value === ""){
        alert("Plz Create Task");
        return ;
    }
    
    inputFeild.classList.add("para-style");
    inputFeild.textContent = inputText.value;
    container.appendChild(inputFeild);
    inputText.value = "";

    
    

    inputFeild.onclick = function(){
        inputFeild.classList.toggle("checked")
    }
    inputFeild.ondblclick = function(){
        container.removeChild(inputFeild);
        localStorage.removeItem("todoList");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the apis you're using is correct. You check the value which is setting using localStorage.setItem(key, value) is correct when saving. You can also go to the applications tab via dev-tools and check the value of the key in the localStorage option.

[image]